# Mocking connection to mySQL database in Node.js for unit-testing

Tags: mysql, node.js, sqlite, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to unit-test my Node.js application using Jest and have ran into the problem of trying to mock a mySQL database in memory. If I understand correctly unit-tests must be fast and not hit the database or file system, they also must also be Isolated/Independent.

While testing functions that hit the file system I have used [mock-fs](https://github.com/tschaub/mock-fs) to mock the fs model and run file read and writes in memory.

The problem I am having with unit-testing functions that hit the database. I am using the [mySQL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) module to communicate with a mySQL server. So my question is, is there a way to run a mySQL database in memory ?
I have seen information on using SQLite3 in memory, I have tired mocking the mySQL module and using a SQLite3 database ran in memory as a drop in replacement, however this causes problems because the SQL syntax is different between mySQL and SQLite3.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Advise:  Don't get caught up in unit test "best practices" to the point that the tests are nullified due to inconsistent, unrealistic conditions. The point of testing in isolation is to have control over and to monitor input / output to a particular software component.  If by mocking another component you loose control over such input/output, then what is actually being tested?  If SQLite requires different SQL format that would require undue tweaking and manipulation of the testing environment, then you're not actually testing expected environment, nor are you testing realistic input/output.

Comment: A mock backend call to a database routine should return a pre-determined set of data that matches certain conditions which are being tested... like "A set of rows with null values in this foreign-key field".  Then execute and test the success of adding foreign-key value (i.e. establishing relationship) by another mock backend call that inspects the addition of foreign-key values being submitted and verify they fall within expected ranges, etc.  If you are simply replacing one database with another without the purposeful preparation of input and inspection of output, then what is being tested?

Comment: You can satisfy white-box testing for a unit test without completely replacing the database if instead your "mock" backend object is simply an intermediary which ensures input conditions and verifies output conditions.  It could simply mean code that inspects data retrieved from database to ensure the rows match the condition being tested, or possibly even replacing database query conditions with precise testing constraints before submission to a test database.